Linux Kernel keeps retransmitting data already ACKed by peer
I have the strange issue that a session without obvious cause hangs and timeouts. The session is a syslog stream with rather high volume, and traffic only flows from client to server. In capture files I see that the client keeps re-transmitting a certain segment, although this segment has already been ACKed by the server, and is almost immediately ACKed with a higher ackno after every retransmission.

The screenshot shows the final packets of the session. Based on the timestamps in the leftmost column the re-transmissions and the ACKs are easily recognizable. It looks like the ACK from the server does not reach the socket, or is ignored by it. There is absolutely nothing suspicious visible in the capture when the problem starts.
The capture has been produced on the client.
Any ideas what could cause this?
The server responses also contain DSACKs, but we already disabled DSACK and SACK and the problem still occurs. The only otherwise notable thing is that this session passes through a bond device on the client, but this should not affect TCP at all IMO.
Happens on Linux kernel 5.10.

Can you run a tcpdump on the other machine at the same time? This usually means that the ACKs are not being received by the, so you would see (or in this case, not see) the missing acks there.
